# Convert date to standard format

Tags: perl

How can we use Perl to change a date to standard format?

For example, if the date value is `1/2/2015` then we need to convert it to `01/02/2015`.

Comment: There is nothing *standard* about `01/02/2015`. You need to explain your problem much better. Describe the scenario. Where is this date string coming from? Is that day/month/year or month/day/year? Is the input format always the same? Is there anything else you can tell us that may help us to help you?

Comment: Here Date is 1/2/2015 in m/d/yyyy that we need to convert to standard pattern mm/dd/yyyy.

Comment: Okay that helps. But is your input always `m/d/y` and you want to zero-fill the month and day to two characters?

Comment: As am new to perl, am trying the below solution as its giving error                 use POSIX qw(strftime);

my $date1 = strftime "%-m/%-d/%Y", '1/2/2015' ;
print $date1;

Comment: If the date is 10 then it comes 1/10/2015 and if month is 10 then 10/10/2015.....What am trying to say is date format is not proper and we need to convert to MM/DD/YYYY

Comment: @user2452689: I don't understand why you are avoiding my questions. Are you trying to make it difficult for us to help you?

Comment: Firstly, StackOverflow isn't here to write your code for you. You should show us the code that you have tried.

Secondly, you need to get a lot better at defining your problem. Your question is very vague.

Thirdly, converting date and time formats is one of the most common questions on Stack Overflow. Did you make any effort to search the site before posting your question?

Comment: which standard? In the international standard ISO 8601 dates must be in the form "YYYY-MM-DD"

Answer (score 4):

There's no need for a module to do this -- you can just pull all the numeric fields out and reformat them with [`sprintf`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html)

This program shows a program that defines the subroutine `standardise_date` which will take a malformed date and reformat it it

```
use strict;
use warnings;

say standardise_date('1/2/2015');

sub standardise_date {
    sprintf "%02d/%02d/%04d", shift =~ /\d+/g;
}
```

#### output

```
01/02/2015
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [Time::Piece](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/Time-Piece-1.30/Piece.pm) for parsing dates.[Refer here](http://www.strftime.net/) for pattern tokens

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Piece;

my $t = Time::Piece->strptime("1/2/2015",
                                "%m/%d/%Y");
print $t->strftime("%m/%d/%Y");
```

Comment: You are pointing to the docs of a totally different module with your _Refer here_. And it's on a specific version using search.cpan.org. Try http://www.strftime.net/ instead. :)